# Running Filebeat in windows

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I set up filebeat on windows recently using these instructions

https://www.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat

but it forces me to keep a cmd prompt open running the command

filebeat.exe -c filebeat.yml

I am wondering if there is a way to run this as a background process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try walking through the full [Getting Started guide for Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html). There are instructions for Windows. Basically the instructions are:

1. Extract the download file anywhere.
2. Move the extracted directory into Program Files.

   ```
   PS > mv filebeat-5.1.2-windows-x86_64 "C:\Program Files\Filebeat"
   ```
3. Install the filebeat service.

   ```
   PS > cd "C:\Program Files\Filebeat"
   PS C:\Program Files\Filebeat> powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File .\install-service-filebeat.ps1
   ```
4. Edit the filebeat.yml config file and test your config.

   ```
   PS C:\Program Files\Filebeat> .\filebeat.exe -e test config
   ```
5. (Optional) Run Filebeat in the foreground to make sure everything is working correctly. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit.

   ```
   PS C:\Program Files\Filebeat> .\filebeat.exe -c filebeat.yml -e -d "*"
   ```
6. Start the service.

   ```
   PS > Start-Service filebeat
   ```

And if you need to stop it, use `Stop-Service filebeat`. You might need to stop it and start it if you want to make changes to the config.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the help.
I tried to use the Start-Service but powershell says cannot find any service with service name filebeat

Comment: Did the `.\install-service-filebeat.ps1` script complete successfully? That's what adds the service.

Comment: I did all of these steps succesfully. I needed to stopped and never cuold start it again. Someone can help me with that!! please!!